# MVC custom decimal modelbinder: RequiredAttribute not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I've thrown together a custom `ModelBinder` for decimal numbers, which should take into account the current user's decimal separator when a value is posted.
Everything is working as intended, except for one thing: If I post an empty value, the basic `Required` validator won't fire, and instead it'll go through my code as normal, and throw a `FormatException` which in turn gets turned into a ModelState error by `DefaultModelBinder`.

When looking at the [source code for DefaultModelBinder](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs) I can see that inside the method `SetProperty` the `Required` attribute is taken into account, but I have no idea how to make this play well with my own binder.

Below is the code for my validator:

Global.asax.cs:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

DecimalModelBinder.cs:

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                                     ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var modelState = new ModelState {Value = valueResult};
        object result = null;

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var attemptedValue =
            bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName).AttemptedValue;

        // Depending on CultureInfo, the NumberDecimalSeparator can be "," or "."
        // Both "." and "," should be accepted, but aren't.
        var wantedSeperator = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        var alternateSeperator = (wantedSeperator == "," ? "." : ",");

        if (attemptedValue.IndexOf(wantedSeperator, StringComparison.Ordinal) == -1
            && attemptedValue.IndexOf(alternateSeperator, StringComparison.Ordinal) != -1)
        {
            attemptedValue =
                attemptedValue.Replace(alternateSeperator, wantedSeperator);
        }

        try
        {
            if (!(bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType
                && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attemptedValue)))
                result = decimal.Parse(attemptedValue, NumberStyles.Any);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);

        return result;
    }
}
```

And lastly my viewmodel:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I remember having a similar problem, the value is defaulted to 0. `default(decimal)`. I either made it nullable (`decimal?`) or turned it into a string.

Comment: @Silvermind Yeah, I know, but that's not the problem, really. I expected my `RequiredAttribute` to run *before* the actual modelbinding occured (as it does when using the `DefaultModelBinder`). Mostly so the validationmessage would tell the client that it's a required field, rather than `'' is not valid for Value`

Comment: Why do you feel the need to write a custom model binder when the framework already has full globalization support?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Because the framework takes the localized settings (being a comma-separator), while everything passed from javascript will always be with a decimal dot. Even then, many users here would use either a dot or a comma, no matter what's "normal" for their localization. I just want to prevent *forcing* a way onto them.

Comment: @Kippie - the framework, if configured correctly, can take whatever format you want.. there is absolutely no need to by pass it like this.  the jquery validation also has localization support as well, which you can install.